# expansion of locally defined variable in e

Tags: python, shell

ex.sh has the following lines

```
BASE_PATH=/home/geetha/app1
LIB_PATH=${BASE_PATH}
CFG_PATH=${BASE_PATH}/cfg
```

I want to extract these variables in a python script. 
Is there a way i can get expanded values of these variables.

for example, the python script should be able to get

```
CFG_PATH=/home/geetha/app1/cfg
```

is there a command, by which i can get the expanded value?
    cmd ex.sh ex1.sh
ex1.sh should contain all the expanded values.

Comment: Is the Python script called from your shell script, or does the Python script call the shell script?

Comment: And is the code in the shell script ounder your control, i.e. can you change it at will?

Comment: Are the variables exported so they could be captured by a sub-process?

Comment: python script calls the shell script. python scripts should get the values of the variable from the shell script.

Comment: Yes, the script is under my control

Answer (score 0):

If you call the shell script as a subprocess, the value of the shell-internal variables won't be accessible to your Python script.

The usual way of communicatinf data back from a shell script is to print the data to stdout (or a pipe, if you need stdout for a different purpose), and then parse that output in the calling process.